# Regex Multiline Capitalize all first letter of words and remove space notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I made this regex demo (working) here: https://regex101.com/r/WSwEbY/6

When I use it in notepad ++, it doesn't work with multiple lines:

```
hello ladies how are you Today
hello ladies how are you Today

-> result is on a single line:
helloLadiesHowAreYouTodayHelloLadiesHowAreYouToday
```

Informations:

```
search: [^\w]+(\w) 
replaceby: \U$1
n++version: 7.5.8
```

I also try to check 'multiline' or add '$' to en of the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you tried to match everything that is not a word character:

```
[^\w]
```

However, the new line character `\n` is also not a word character so it will also be matched by `[^\w]` and replaced.

You should exclude `\n` from the character class as well:

```
[^\w\n]+(\w)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X4pC9M/1)

Comment: It's working. Is it always possible to keep the first char as a lower case ?

Comment: I think you need another regex for that. @Tyvain

Answer (score 0):

How about matching just the space or the start(`^`) with multiline flag?

```
(?:^| +)(\w)
```

sub:

```
\U$1
```

Comment: Considering that in OP's working demo, the first letter is not capitalised, I think not capitalising the first letter of the line is OP's intention. OP is only trying to get the results to be on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to not matching newlines in the repeated character set, you should also alternate with a check for if you're at the start of a line - that way the first word on a line will be capitalized as well. Use the `m` flag so that `^` matches the start of a line:

```
(?:^|[^\w\n]+)(\w)
```

Replace with:

```
\U$1
```

Output:

```
HelloLadiesHowAreYouToday
IAmFineThankYou
```

https://regex101.com/r/dsOcOD/1

Comment: Considering that in OP's working demo, the first letter is not capitalised, I think not capitalising the first letter of the line is OP's intention. OP is only trying to get the results to be on separate lines.